# SQL Command to search from Java program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am attempting to allow keyboard input from my Java Project to search for a Car License number (VARCHAR), from my database. I am getting an error in my tester class about SQL syntax error. What would be the correct procedure so that when I search for a license it will display that license. Thanks in advance

```
public Car getCar(String searchLicense) {
    Car foundCar = new Car();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                "select * from eflow.registration.cLicense where="+searchLicense);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            foundCar = new Car(resultSet.getInt("cID"), resultSet.getString("cLicense"),
                    resultSet.getInt("cJourneys"), resultSet.getString("cUsername"),
                    resultSet.getString("cPassword").toString());
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return foundCar;
}
```

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.cLicense where=' at line 1

Comment: what should `eflow.registration.cLicense` be?

Comment: A brief look at the code ... cLicense is a field right? You select from a TABLE not a field. Your where clause is also incorrect. Change it to  " where cLicense = 'VALUE'

Comment: cLicense is a Column in the DB table

Comment: without knowing the schema ... try "select * from eflow.registration where cLicense = '" + searchLicense + "';"

Comment: Please read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and read up on SQL injection and how you can avoid it using a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

You missing single quote and column name also..

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                    "select * from eflow.registration.cLicense where cLicenseName='"+searchLicense+"'");
```

Better solution,try this..

```
  resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                "select * from eflow.registration.cLicense where cLicenseName like '%"+searchLicense+"%'");
```

Comment: he select from db.table.column `eflow.registration.cLicense` did you check that, this is a second error you solved :)

Comment: But he did not mention any column name as well as table name specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The direct problem you're talking about it that you are missing quotation on your query, since it is a string. so what @Dakoda suggested in the comments should solve it.

however, the bigger issue here is that you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), as you are allowing user input into your query. If I'll put input like `xxx' or 'a' ='a` I'll be able to fetch your entire database.

You should use parameterized query to protect yourself

Comment: Here is the message I get after altering the code

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1